# How to remove the whitespace below the text?

Tags: html, css

<kbd>[**PLAYGROUND HERE**](http://jsbin.com/qirokejiqoqu/1/)</kbd>

Dead simple question:

HTML:

```
<div>Hello World</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-size: 70px;
}
```

Result:

[image]

What is the easiest (no hacks please) method to remove the whitespace below the text, i.e. to position the text such that its baseline is at the bottom of the element?

Desired result:

[image]

<kbd>[**PLAYGROUND HERE**](http://jsbin.com/qirokejiqoqu/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Have you tried setting the margins and padding to 0?  Doing an absolute positioning should also work.

Comment: In your example, where would you expect the bottom part of a 'g' character to go? Outside the pink? For example: [http://www.cssdesk.com/96z4x](http://www.cssdesk.com/96z4x)

Comment: Yes, outside the pink!

Comment: Not necessarily headings, it could be anything, normal text, labels, etc.

Comment: [This article on Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/17/css-baseline-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/) is a little old (2012 and a bit wordy!), but an interesting read. It talks specifically about the baseline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alter the vales for `line-height` and `padding-top`

```
div {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-size: 70px;
    line-height: 48px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/q9osxyrp/1/)**

```css
div {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-size: 70px;
    line-height: 48px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello - g - World</div>
```

OR (Similar to @Michal's answer)...

You could add a height to the div which is LESS than the font-size eg:

```css
div {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
    font-size: 70px;
    height: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello - g - World</div>
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the line-height varies between typefaces, this example is off in [Verdana](http://jsfiddle.net/trf6m9ta/), for example.

Comment: @misterManSam You'd have to set the `line-height` accordingly - depending on your font-family.

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained that the height of the pink box is fixed. Here is an updated question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26160964/247243

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it is making space for 'lower' letters like 'j'. You can set height of div but this is like it would look like:

```
div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-size: 70px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
    height: 70px
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3q0Lqz4L/)