# How to position text on a baseline?

Tags: html, css

<kbd>[**PLAYGROUND HERE**](http://jsbin.com/diyirenajaku/1/edit)</kbd>

HTML:

```
<div class="first">Hello g World</div>
<div class="second">Hello g World</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3); /* For visualization only */
  margin-top: 50px;                       /* For visualization only */
  height: 20px;                           /* This is fixed! */
}

.first {
  font-size: 16px;                        /* This can change */
}

.second {
  font-size: 30px;                        /* This can change */
}
```

Result:

[image]

How would you position the text such that its baseline (the bottom of "Hello") is aligned with the bottom of the pink box, i.e.:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this regardless of the `font-size`?

<kbd>[**PLAYGROUND HERE**](http://jsbin.com/diyirenajaku/1/edit)</kbd>

Comment: What is the application here? Are you trying to achieve vertical rhythm? At the moment, you're trying to get the background colour of a box to line up with the box contents, which is going to be an exercise in frustration because browsers position text roughly in the vertical center of a line, as defined by the `line-height` property.

Comment: Yes, vertical phythm is the purpose here!

Comment: The demo method you're using--setting the background colour of an element and trying to place that element's text on top of it--will not work. If you want to establish a grid for vertical rhythm, you need to have the grid in another element higher up the dom -- see the background grid that I used in my answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After searching ...and searching I came up with this very awesome [tutorial at adobe's place](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/08/13/one-weird-trick-to-baseline-align-text/) about how to align text to baseline of an element.

**USING PSEUDO-ELEMENT**

I would suggest this one but take a look at all the story bellow (Road from .strut element to a single pseudo-element):

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
}
.first {
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: #9BBCE3;
}
.first::after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="first">Hello g World / With font-size: 24px</div>
</div>
```

**USING  AN EXTRA .STRUT ELEMENT**

- **SCENARIOS AND RULES**

**Rule 1 (Larger Fonts)**: We want the height of the div to be fixed. For example 20px. So, the `font-size` must be equal or less to the `.height` value so as to work.In general,

**~ THE FONT-SIZE MUST BE EQUAL OR LESS THAN THE FIXED HEIGHT.THEN IT WORKS FOR ALL SIZES WITH LESS VALUES**

**Scenario 1**: Suppose that we have larger fonts than the `20px` of this case.

**See it in action:** http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/pvw5xhku/

```css
div.forall {
  width: 700px;
  height: 48px;
  border: thin black solid;
  background-color: #9BBCE3;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.inText {
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
}
.inText3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
}
.strut {
  height: 48px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="forall">
  <div class="inText">Hello g World /With font-size 46px
    <div class="strut"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="forall">
  <div class="inText2">Hello g World /With font-size 32px
    <div class="strut"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="forall">
  <div class="inText3">Hello g World /With font-size 32px
    <div class="strut"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

- **EXPLANATION**

All the magic about this implementation is about the `.strut element`.This is the one with `display:inline-block;` property!
I wondered ...what is that again ?!

The baseline of the **strut** is placed at its bottom margin edge, which is determined solely by the height of the strut in this case. And if the letter span’s line-height is smaller than the strut’s height, the letter’s baseline will move to match! **Unbelievable!**

- **MAIN IMPLEMENTATION**

**See it in action:** http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/bm2yz3ec/

```css
div.forall {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  border: thin black solid;
  background-color: #9BBCE3;
  margin: 10px;
}
.inText {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.intext2 {
  font-size: 9px;
  line-height: 9px;
}
.strut {
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="forall">
  <div class="inText">Hello g World /With font-size 20px
    <div class="strut"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="forall">
  <div>Hello g World / Without font-size
    <div class="strut"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="forall">
  <div class="intext2">Hello g World / with font-size:9px
    <div class="strut"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Great find, but it only works with text on a single line--all the large text examples you've posted break in my browser because my default font is wider than yours. :(  Have you experimented with getting it to work over more than one line?

Comment: This is because the width of .forall element 300px .If you change that will play.But you have right this would be great if it works for new lines . I want to think and I update it if I fix this.Thanks for your notice/

Answer (score 8):

Yes, to some extent: you can manipulate the position of text using a combination of `line-height` and a choice of other properties, including setting margins and padding, or using `position: relative` and `top`. There are other techniques if you only have one line that needs positioning (e.g. if you're creating a drop cap); I will cover positioning techniques that work on one and multiple lines.

There is the rather large caveat to this that type rendering varies between OSes and browsers, and it is going to be difficult to control your text precisely, particularly if you want pixel-perfect control.

By default, browsers position text roughly in the middle of the line, as defined by the line height. There is not a defined baseline for text that is invariant between browsers, so positioning varies between browsers.

The idea when setting up vertical rhythm is to have all your text falling at certain intervals. To do this, you need to control font size (which most people do anyway), line height, and anything that will add vertical space to your design: borders, padding, and margin. You select your "rhythm unit"--in your case, 20px--and then set your text to align with it. Your line height should be equal to your rhythm unit (i.e. 20px); for large font sizes, use multiple of the rhythm unit (e.g. 40px, 60px) to ensure the text stays in rhythm. The combination of borders, padding, and margin should add up to your rhythm unit to keep everything in line.

I've made the following [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3b8Lq0av/1/) to illustrate the next piece of code.

As mentioned earlier, text gets vertically centered(-ish) by the browser, so it doesn't sit nicely on a grid; the text baseline moves around when using different font sizes. Here are a couple of ways to deal with that.

Here's our sample HTML:

```
<article>
  <section>
    <h2>Title!</h2>
    <div class="first">Hello g World<br />Lorem ipsum...</div>
    <div class="second">Hello g World<br />Lorem ipsum...</div>
    <div class="first">Hello g World<br />Lorem ipsum...</div>
  </section>
</article>
```

We'll give it the following basic css:

```
article {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 20px;  /* 20px is our "unit of rhythm" */
}

div {
  margin: 20px;
}

h2 {
   font-size: 24px;
   line-height: 40px;  /* double our rhythm unit */
}

.first {
   font-size: 16px;
}

.second {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 40px;  /* double our rhythm unit */
}
```

### Using `position: relative` and `top`:

Visually align text by positioning it relatively to the background grid.

Give the `section` element the class `rel` and add the following CSS:

```
.rel, .rel .first, .rel .second {
   position: relative;
}
.rel .first {
    top: 4px;
}
.rel .second {
    top: 9px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3b8Lq0av/1/) - half way down the page

This pushes the text down from its natural position. Unfortunately, this alignment has to be done by eye and yep, it does vary from browser to browser. Pages are usually internally consistent--i.e. text lines up with the grid, even if it is uniformly a couple of pixels higher in some browsers.

### Using `padding` and/or `margin`

The sum of the top and bottom padding must equal our unit of rhythm. Again, alignment has to be done by eye and may differ between browsers.

```
.ptop .first {
    padding-top: 24px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    margin: 0 20px; /* get rid of the massive gap! */
}

.ptop .second {
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0 20px; /* get rid of the massive gap! */
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3b8Lq0av/1/) - scroll to the bottom

You can also use margins, but care must be taken with collapsing margins to ensure the rhythm stays intact.

That is a whistlestop guide to a couple of methods for establishing vertical rhythm. I've skimmed over the details, so I would advise you to read up about this online -- there is a [great article about vertical rhythm at 24ways](http://24ways.org/2006/compose-to-a-vertical-rhythm/), and another good one at [A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/article/settingtypeontheweb). There are also some vertical rhythm generators to stop you doing too much pixel-fiddling yourself.

Comment: Do you have a good resource for reading about the idea of "rhythm" in web programming?

Comment: @Thomas [Vertical Rhythm with Compass](http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/vertical-rhythm-compass) is a particularly good resource because it has links to three classic vertical rhythm articles (including the two I linked to in the last paragraph of my answer) and it shows you how to set up vertical rhythm using the [CSS/SASS framework Compass](http://compass-style.org/).

Answer (score 4):

try adding `line-height` attribute as well:

```
div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3); /* For visualization only */
  margin-top: 50px;                       /* For visualization only */
  height: 20px;                           /* This is fixed! */
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

### UPDATE

Setting `height` and `line-height` to the same value aligns text vertically by center:

#### [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/wubocabizure/1/edit)

If you only use `16px` and `30px` that might be enough for you. If you need this to work with all values, I would suggest you use another layout, something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="align-bottom">Hello g world</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @MishaMoroshko, yes sorry, I was not clear enough. Is it possible for you to change the layout?

Comment: Ideally, the layout wouldn't change. But, I would be interested to see a solution with a different layout that works for all `font-size`s.

Comment: Setting line height this way will align the middle of text with the middle of box, it will not align baseline of text with baseline of box.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a CSS property for this, and I don't think you can determine it programmatically.

However, you can adjust the `div`'s height with JavaScript, assuming the section of the font above the baseline is approx. 80%:

```
var d = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i = 0 ; i < d.length ; i++) {
  d[i].style.height= d[i].offsetHeight*0.8+'px';
}
```

Remove the hard-coded `div` style height first.

Fiddle:  **http://jsfiddle.net/38eLft8q/1/**

Comment: Yep, I think your JavaScript approach is better than some css mockery for this issue. Vertical rhythm approach won't work because line heights are variable. Height should be adjusted for each font.

Comment: @jzelenkov Your comment is rather ironic since all that this javascript does is to set the style properties of text--i.e. css "mockery".

Comment: @ialarmedalien good point. I shouldn't be writing when I am tired

Answer (score 1):

A little tricky and maybe not bulletproof, but so far:

**HTML**

```
<div class="first"  title="Hello g World"></div>
<div class="second" title="Hello g World"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 20px; /* This is fixed! */
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
   content: attr(title);
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -0.24em;
}

.first {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.second {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/menipuqopesa/1/edit)

*thanks for the challenge :)*

### UPDATES:

For no changes in the question structure we'll keep div's text:

```
<div class="first">Hello g World</div>
<div class="second">Hello g World</div>
```

and a little javascript will create the titles

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div"); 

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {  

    var txt = divs[i].innerHTML;
    divs[i].setAttribute('title', txt);

}
```

finaly some css changes

```
div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 20px; /* This is fixed! */
  text-indent: -9999px;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
   content: attr(title);
   text-indent: 9999px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -0.24em;
}
```

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/menipuqopesa/7/edit)

**If we can change the structure that will be**

**HTML**

```
  <div class="first"><span>Hello g World</span></div>
  <div class="second"><span>Hello g World</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 20px; /* This is fixed! */
  position: relative;
}

div span {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -0.24em;
}
```

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/zokiqetoseno/2/edit)

#### **NOTE**:

- Not checked with different fonts, but i think it's only to calculate
  the bottom part.